# Trying to set a VAR to be the name of a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a DIV with a name assigned to it (actually the database Id).  I'm trying to on click, set a new VAR to be the name of that div (going to use it for a PUT request).

When I log the following it comes back as undefined?

This is the HTML

```
<div class="deleterow" id='removerow' name="${product._id}">
  <img src="images/icons/icon-delete.png" alt="delete button"  />
</div>
```

This is the JS

```
$(document).on('click', '#removerow', function() {
  let id = this.name;
  console.log(id); //undefined
});
```

If I change this.name to just this,  it logs the information with the name correctly as below, so I know it's pulling the product._id correctly.

```
$(document).on('click', '#removerow', function() {
  let id = this;
  console.log(id);
});
```

This will log;

```
<div class="" id="removerow" name="5bfcbf1d181c4573f089a24c">
   <img src="images/icons/icon-delete.png" alt="delete button">
</div>
```

Comment: are you having multiple elements with same id **removerow** in your page? Please check first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with jQuery's [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#removerow', function() {
  let id = $(this).attr('name');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" id="removerow" name="5bfcbf1d181c4573f089a24c">
   <img src="images/icons/icon-delete.png" alt="delete button">
</div>
```

**OR:** You can also use vanilla JavaScript's [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute):

> `getAttribute()` returns the value of a specified attribute on the element. If the given attribute does not exist, the value returned will either be null or "" (the empty string); see Notes for details.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#removerow', function() {
  let id = this.getAttribute('name');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" id="removerow" name="5bfcbf1d181c4573f089a24c">
   <img src="images/icons/icon-delete.png" alt="delete button">
</div>
```